# How to create a generic controller model in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

How can I create a generic model in Ember.js like the following?

```
{{#each item in mythings}}
    {{item}}
{{/item}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in the controller like in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/168/edit).

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
      mythings: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
});
```